# Get data in string using TcpClient

Tags: c#, asp.net, tcpclient

I have a requirement to get the data into a string using `TcpClient`. The site requires authentication as well. I found a snippet to get data into stream but it is throwing

> exception that the connection terminated unexpectedly

. Below is the sample code

```
TcpClient oClient = new TcpClient();
oClient.Connect("xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx", 80);
NetworkStream ns = oClient.GetStream();
StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(ns);
sw.Write(
      string.Format(
                    "GET /{0} HTTP/1.1\r\nUser-Agent: {1}\r\nHost: iq\r\n\r\n",
                             "/",
                             "MyTCPClient")
                      );
sw.Flush();
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
while (true)
{
    int i = ns.ReadByte(); // Inefficient but more reliable 
    if (i == -1) break;  // Other side has closed socket 
    sb.Append((char)i);   // Accrue 'c' to save page data 
}
oClient.Close();
```

How can I include the authentication step as well.

P.S.: Just to summarize, I want to get the html of a page in string using `TcpClient` which involves authentication as well.

**Edit:** I am going for this approach as the URL had period at the end which was being removed by `URI`.

Comment: First off, why only TcpClient? Second, when do you get the exception that the connection terminated unexpectedly? I think you can include normal NetworkCredential with the TCP client, but since you are not specifying which Authentication you are required to use, it is hard to reply on that question...

Comment: I don't see anything here that would perform any authentication. So probably the connection is being closed because you failed to authenticate. You should be using `HttpWebRequest`, which provides HTTP-aware features, such as dealing with request and response headers, and authentication.